# Insert prepared statement works on DB but not the other

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I have a Problem with the following Insert Statement. I Installed Wamp on my local windows machine i have no problem this statement executes as it should. 
 but as soon as i try to run the same insert statement on my cloud hosted ubuntu machine it wont work. I have checked the password and username dbname even field names. i use chrome rest client to call the page. is there something i should know about the environments being different.

```
<?php

Include('Db_Connect.php');

$name = ($_POST['Name']);
$surname = ($_POST['Surname']);
$email = ($_POST['Email']);
$userpassword = ($_POST['mypwd']);


// Encrypt method
$hashed_password = password_hash($userpassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";



// prepare and bind

 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO appuser01 (Name, Surname, Email, UserPwd) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
 $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $surname, $email, $hashed_password);

 $stmt->execute()

 echo "New records created successfully";

 $stmt->close();
 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you get any error-messages? If no, have you enabled error reporting?

Comment: Also missing a `;` after `execute()`, is that just a copy/paste error, or actual code?

Comment: So add some error checking after `->prepare` and `->execute` and then show the `mysqli_error($conn)` that will probably tell you what is wrong, rather than just guessing

Comment: File inclusion in ubuntu is case sensitive. May try checking for the exact file name which is to be included. Or simply enable error reporting to find out what the error is.

Comment: Simple rule when developing on Windows(not case sensitive OS) and running live on UNIX(case sensitive OS) is to keep all filenames as `lower case`